# Java - Eclipse project setting somewhere causes FileNotFound errors

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, intellij-idea, filenotfoundexception

I started a project on one computer using IntelliJ and copied the project across to another computer, setting it up with Eclipse. I read a file named "map.txt" in my project's src directory and everything works fine.

However when I created a new project in eclipse and did pretty much exactly the same thing, it doesn't work. I get file not found exception. I created the file using Eclipse's IDE. I have tried refreshing, and cleaning the project but nothing has worked.

I have a feeling eclipse has some weird project setting for where the current directory is. Unless this is because the first project is a JApplet and the second a JFrame?

Do you guys have any idea how I can fix this problem? No, I'm not accepting absolute path directory as an answer.

Comment: What if you move the file out of src and up one directory?

Comment: yes that worked...thanks, but why is there a difference? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure except that that is how Eclipse is set up. Glad you've got it working, but you'll have to wait for better minds to give you the whys.

Comment: For the resource to be picked up, it should be in the classpath of the vm that you are launching (via launch configuration). By default project root, would be in the classpath. Eclipse has a notion of source directories. if you create java project, one source project named 'src' gets created automatically. It only has one output directory. By default its 'bin' and is hidden in package explorer view. To ensure that the src folder is a source folder, go to Right click -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Java Build Path -> Source tab.